# How do you change skins with spine? libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, spine

Is there anyway to change skins programatically using the spine-libgdx runtime?

If not, is there at least a way to remove individual body parts or add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd change skins like this.

```
Skeleton skeleton = new Skeleton(skeletonData);
...
skeleton.setSkin("goblin");
```